# When does a model get updated after the model data has changed?

Tags: sapui5

There is a method named updateBindings(true?) in openui5. But I'm not sure when I have to invoke it. Sometimes, setting the modified data to a model causes view changes, which indicates the underlying model data actually gets changed. Sometimes it won't work.

The first example demonstrates that the model doesn't get changed without updateBindings(true).
http://jsbin.com/hulavutoha/edit?html,css,output

The second example derives from the first one. But the model gets updated even without updateBindings(true).
http://jsbin.com/lepuladivu/edit?html,css,output

So, what's the difference between the two examples? When do I need to invoke updateBindings(true) on a model so that it will get updated? What's the intent of the parameter **true** passed to updateBindings()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a console print in your formatter function

```
formatter : function(books) {
    console.log("go!!!");  
    return books[0];
}
```

you can see that in the first example the function is not executed.
This because if you change a leaf property the linked conponent in thew view (using data-binding) receive the change event ***only if it bind exactly the leaf property***.

P.S.
Instead to use `getData`

```
var data = oModel.getData();
data.books[0] = "my book";
oModel.setData(data);
```

you can use `getProperty`

```
var data = oModel.getProperty("/"); 
data.books[0] = "my book";
//oModel.setProperty("/", data);
```

In this mode the last line is not required